# Why don't we have <cstdfloat> in C++?

Tags: c++, cstdint

Why doesn't C++ have <cstdfloat> header for floats like it has <cstdint> for integers?

**EDIT :**

By <cstdfloat> I mean header that provides typedefs for float and double. Much like qreal typedef in Qt. Hope my question is clear now.

Comment: <cstdint> is actually not part of Standard C++

Comment: What is it specifically from cstdint that you would like for floats?

Comment: @Neil It will be added in C++0x though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often an application needs exactly 16 bits for an integer for, say, a bitfield, but having exactly 16 bits for a float is kind of useless. Manipulating bits in an integer is easy, so having exactly 16 is nice. Manipulating bits in a float requires casting it to an integer, making a `float16` type rather extraneous.

By the same token, having an integral type capable of storing (and also performing math on) pointers is useful, but who ever needs to convert a pointer value to a floating point value, then perform floating point math on it, then convert it back to a pointer?

The point is that most of the functionality in `stdint.h` (or `cstdint` for C++, except that `stdint.h` is a C99 header and isn't technically part of C++) doesn't apply to floating point values.

Answer (score 3):

Are you perhaps looking for [`<float.h>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Float.h) and its C++ brother `<cfloat>` instead?

Comment: <float.h> is a different thing. I am talking about header that provides typedefs for float and double. Much like qreal typedef in Qt. Hope you understand my question now.

Comment: Then you should specify that in your question.  Your question is incredibly vague.

Comment: @Rosenfield : Sorry. Edited my question now.